# R - Group by dplyr, and remove duplicates only if ALL members in group are duplicated

Tags: r, duplicates, dplyr

I have a large data frame  many duplicates in a single column. I am trying to parse the data frame so that only one entry per duplicate remains, **UNLESS all entries are duplicates.**  (Couldn't find any stackoverflow answers that helped with the second part...)

Example df code:

```
mydf <- data.frame(accession=c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D"), gene=c("unknown", "red1", "red2", "blue", "green1", "green2", "unknown", "unknown2", "violet"), ident=c(100.0, 95.3, 80.2, 65.1, 94.2, 100.0, 97.1, 90.0, 86))
```

df looks like this:

```
   accession   gene      ident
1  A           unknown   100.0   
2  A           red1      95.3
3  A           red2      80.2
4  A           blue      65.1
5  B           green1    94.2
6  B           green2    100.0
7  C           unknown   97.1
8  C           unknown2  90.0
9  D           violet    86.0
```

And my desired output table is this:

```
   accession   gene      ident   
2  A           red1      95.3
6  B           green2    100.0
7  C           unknown   97.1
8  C           unknown2  90.0
```

Where only one unique value for `accession` is kept, based on having a "known" `gene` with the highest `ident`, **UNLESS** all duplicated entries for a particular `accession` contain the string `unknown*`.

I'm getting stuck at the last part -- keeping all rows for a duplicated `accession` if `gene` contains `unknown*`.  This is what I have so far:

```
library(dplyr)
mydf$dup <- duplicated(mydf$accession, fromLast = FALSE)|duplicated(mydf$accession, fromLast = TRUE)
mydf <- mydf %>% group_by(accession) %>% mutate(count=n())
mydf <- subset.data.frame(mydf, mydf$dup == TRUE)
mydf <- mydf %>% group_by(accession) %>% filter(!grepl("unknown", gene)) %>% top_n(1,ident)
```

which gives:

```
   accession   gene      ident   dup    count   
2  A           red1      95.3    TRUE   4
6  B           green2    100.0   TRUE   2
```

My instinct is to do an `if` statement:

```
mydf <- mydf %>% group_by(accession) %>% 
if(count(grepl("unknown", mydf$gene))!= mydf$count)
      {filter(!grepl("unknown", gene))} 
%>% top_n(1, ident)
```

but I'm running into an error:

> Error in if (.) count(grepl("unknown", mydf$gene)) != mydf$count else
>   { :    argument is not interpretable as logical In addition: Warning
>   message: In if (.) count(grepl("unknown", mydf$gene)) != mydf$count
>   else { :   the condition has length > 1 and only the first element
>   will be used

What's the correct solution? I'm not married to dplyr if there a better way! Thanks!

Comment: Why is accession `D` removed?

Comment: I only wanted to keep those values that had duplicates (this values require further analysis in my real dataset).  D is a unique value, and so gets filtered out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
mydf %>%
  group_by(accession) %>%
  mutate(n = n()) %>%
  filter(n > 1) %>%
  mutate(ident_rnk = min_rank(ident),
         ident_rnk = if_else(grepl("unknown",gene),-1L,ident_rnk)) %>%
  top_n(n = 1,wt = ident_rnk) %>%
  select(accession,gene,ident)
```

Comment: This works! I'm not sure the advantage of your answer vs. @psidom's answer; but this is more in line with my initial thought.

Comment: @moxed tbh, Psidom's answer feels somewhat cleaner to me, tho I could edit mine to be more in line with theirs to streamline it slightly...

Answer (score 3):

Another option:

1) firstly arrange data frame and sort `unkown` to the end of each group and at the same time sort `ident` in descending order;

2) filter per group, make sure the number of rows for the group is larger than 1, and then either the first `gene` starts with `unknown` which means the whole group contains `unknown` since `unkown` has been sorted to the end or take the first row:

```
mydf %>% 
    group_by(accession) %>% 
    arrange(startsWith(gene, 'unknown'), desc(ident)) %>% 
    filter(n() > 1 & (startsWith(first(gene), 'unknown') | row_number() == 1))

# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   accession [3]
#  accession     gene ident
#      <chr>    <chr> <dbl>
#1         B   green2 100.0
#2         A     red1  95.3
#3         C  unknown  97.1
#4         C unknown2  90.0
```

Comment: Any idea why I'm getting an error: "Error in arrange_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: non-character object(s)." ; I've tried changing 'gene' and 'ident' to characters with the same error still occuring.

Comment: You probably have strings as factors in the data frame, try `stringsAsFactor = F` when constructing the data frame or read the data in.

Comment: Even though @joran's answer works, I'm still interested in what's throwing the error.  Also is there an advantage with this method vs @joran's? I'm still new to R and trying to learn more!

Comment: `stringsAsFactor` works for me. As for advantages, it's hard to say. Maybe you could benchmark the speed?

Comment: Yup, strings as factors was the problem. For future reference and googling novices, this fixes the issue: 
mydf <- data.frame(lapply(mydf, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)